# Android Download manager ERROR_CANNOT_RESUME

Tags: android

`DownloadManager` возвращает статус `ERROR_CANNOT_RESUME`.

Небольшие файлы скачивает, а большие, которые весят *+- 100 мб* возвращают эту ошибку (не все). Скачиваю ауди.

Как исправить это?

Скачиваю так:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(item.getAudioUrl());
String name = getName();//Random name
DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri)
    .setTitle("Dummy File")// Title of the Download Notification
    .setDescription("Downloading")// Description of the Download Notification
     .setVisibleInDownloadsUi(false)
     .setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(MyActivity.this, DIR_TYPE, name);

DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
long downloadId = downloadManager.enqueue(request);
```

Comment: Может места не хватает? Или `getName()` выдаёт не такой уж и рандом  - и имена всё-таки совпадают?

Answer (score 1):

Я уже нашел причину.
Причина кроется в том что DownloadManager используєт eTAG. А некоторие силки у меня не использують его.